# The safer way to encrypt

Tags: php, curl, encryption, paypal

Related to [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23907633/paypal-development-encrypt-transactions-php-p12) i have a new one.

What is a safer way to send encrypted data via https.

1. using [signAndEncrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23907633/paypal-development-encrypt-transactions-php-p12) function with openssl_pkcs7_encrypt and send return array via form element...

   ```
   $encryptedData = "-----BEGIN PKCS7-----" . str_replace("\n", "", <br/>   $encryptedDataReturn['encrypted_data']) ."-----END PKCS7-----";

       $encryptedRequest=<<<PPHTML
     <html>
       <header>
       </header>

       <body onload="document.getElementById('paypal_form').submit();">
         <br/><br/><br/><br/>
         <center>
           <h2>Please wait, your order is being processed and you
               will be redirected to the paypal website.
           </h2>
         </center>
         <form id="paypal_form" method="POST" action="{$this->gatewayUrl}">
           <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
           <input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="$encryptedData">
         </form>
       </body>
     </html>
   ```

   PPHTML;

or using curl like this

2.

```
$curlOptions = array (
            CURLOPT_URL => Config::MERCHANT_SANDBOX_SIGNATURE_ENDPOINT,
            CURLOPT_VERBOSE => 1,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
            CURLOPT_CAINFO => $this->publicCertificate,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_POST => 1,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($data)
    );


    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch,$curlOptions);

    //Sending our request - $response will hold the API response
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

I'am trying to find the safest way to send data to the paypal api.
First i mixed both of the functions, and added the encrypted nvp to the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`. But that gave me a bunch of errors from paypal. So i have done a double encryption. When i leave the postfields unencrypted, the paypal api gives me `success`.   
My Questions: 
1. Is it secure enough, to use `curl` with public certificate ?  
2. Is it possible to use the `pkcs7` encryption (or similar encryption) with `curl`?

3. Am I right in assuming that it isnt possible to encrypt the postfields, before send data via curl/https to paypal, because when i do that, paypal give me failure responses? 
 Please help.
Greetings ninchen

Comment: if using https adding anything else seems pointless

Comment: Is there a reason you are using PayPal Standard and encrypting these buttons instead of using the [Button API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/button-manager/BMCreateButton_API_Operation_NVP/)? Or even doing ExpressCheckout?

Comment: @PP_MSI_Aaron Maybe the better solution to use the Button API, but why? I use ExpressCheckout. You ask, because the html form looks like PayPal Standard?

Comment: The HTML form IS PayPal Standard. Creating a dynamic button with encrypted= requires you to upload your cert to your paypal account. See the [Developer's Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/encryptedwebpayments/) for Securing PayPal Standard Buttons..

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to crypto & security, your first answer should be to do whatever is standard. It's standard for a reason, and can be expected to be reasonably secure. If vulnerabilities are discovered, you'll need to update, but then again so will everyone else. Trying a clever trick to be "more secure" usually means that you end up with something that is less so.

See [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own) for an extended discussion.